# Aligning two values in a string (PHP)

Tags: php, string, algorithm, data-manipulation

I have two values: both can be either an integer or a string.

I need to format (using PHP) my output string in a very specific format.

1. Output string's length needs to be 10.
2. First variable needs to be "aligned" on the left.
3. Second variable needs to be "aligned" on the right.
4. Remaining unused characters (if any) should be filled with spaces.

For example:

```
In:
$var1 = 123456; $var2 = 'XX';
Result:
'123456  XX'

In:
$var1 = 1; $var2 = 9876;
Result:
'1     9876'
```

Any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: Maybe you should show use what you have so far tried

Comment: And what do you do when the sum of lengths of two strings exceed 10? Cut one or the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while(strlen($var1.$var2) < 10)
{    
    $var2 = " ".$var2; // or "&nbsp;" instead of " "
}

$final = $var1.$var2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str_pad` function.

Try this,

```
$var1 = 12;
$var2 = 'XX';
$max_len = 15;
$output = $var1 . str_pad(' ', $max_len-(strlen($var1.$var2))) . $var2;
echo '<pre>'. $output . '</pre>';

$var1 = 1234;
$var2 = 'XX';
$max_len = 15;
$output = $var1 . str_pad(' ', $max_len-(strlen($var1.$var2))) . $var2;
echo '<pre>'. $output . '</pre>';
```

You can set maximum length to $max_len (In your question, it's 10)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i = 0; $i < 10 - (strlen($var1) + strlen($var2)); $i++) $result .= " ";
$result = $var1.$result.$var2;
```

Answer (score 0):

this is very ruff around the edges but might get you started?

```
<?php

  function    my_custom_format($var1,$var2){

    $limit  = 10;     
    $total  = strlen($var1.$var2);       
    $spaces = $limit-$total;       
    $string = $var1 . str_repeat('&nbsp;',($spaces<0)?0:$spaces) . $var2; 
    echo      $string;

  }

  $var1     = 1234567890234;
  $var2     = 'XX';

  my_custom_format($var1,$var2);

?>
```

Comment: edited to account for when the sum totals more than 10, spaces are just not present at that point, Im not sure how you wanted to handle that.